# Combining a line from plot to marks from errorbar in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

When plotting data on matplotlib, I use errorbar to place the scatter marks and plot to draw the linear fit result. I store the errorbar output in an array I feed to `fig.ax.legend()` to tell it what to place in the legend (I follow matplotlib conventions). Is there a way to tell it to add the fit line in the same legend line?

Answer (score 2):

In matplotlib at least v1.2.1, you can [add a tuple of lines that should be overlayed for the legend entry](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handler):

```
from pylab import *
fig = figure(1)
fig.clear()
x = linspace(0,2*pi,100)
y = sin(x)
yerr = y*.1
e = errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerr,label='data')
l, = plot(x,y,lw=3)
legend([(e,l)],['data & fit'])
```

[image: combined line and errorbar legend]

Comment: I tried this. I plot inside a class and I place the errorbar and the plot in a list (``self.tolegs == []``, ``self.tolegs.append(e,p)``). When I try to place the legend I get an error: ``AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_artists'``

Comment: How are you using `self.tolegs`?

Comment: Also, I assume it was a typo to give two arguments to `self.tolegs.append`?  I get an error in python when I give it more than one argument.